# Как вывести информацию из двух связанных моделей ForeignKey на Django

Tags: python, django, foreign-key

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField('Название статьи ', max_length=200)
    article_text = models.TextField('текст')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('дата')
    img_post = models.ImageField("Изображение", upload_to="img")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Статья'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Статьи'

class Image(models.Model):
    Article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField("Изображение", upload_to="img")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Изображение'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Изображения'
```

home urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('<int:home_id>/', views.detail, name = 'detail'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article, Image
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def index(request):
    latest_atricles_list = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    paginator = Paginator(latest_atricles_list, 6)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number,)
    return render(request, 'home/list.html', {'latest_atricles_list': latest_atricles_list,'page_obj': page_obj})




def detail(request, home_id):
    a = Article.objects.get(id= home_id)
    return render(request, 'home/detail.html',  {'a': a,})
```

detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{a.article_title}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h2>{{a.article_title}}</h2>

<p>{{a.article_text}}</p>

<em>{{a.pub_date}}</em>

<img src="/media/{{ a.img_post }}">





{% for %}

{# вот тут должны отображаться фото #}

{%endfor%}


{% endblock %}
```

Здравствуйте, я делаю сайт портфолио. На главной странице выводится карточки выполненных работ. Карточки состоят из обложки работы, даты, заголовка и кнопки "подробнее" (на этом этапе всё работает отлично).
По нажатию кнопки, нас переносит в detail.html. Там выводится полная информация о карточке, так же остальные фотографии этой работы. Именно с этими фотографиями у меня возникли проблемы, никак не могу их вывести. Гуглил много раз, но ничего не работало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь у вас настроены `MEDIA_URL` и `MEDIA_ROOT`?

Вам нужно вписать `url` картинки в тэг `img`:

```
<img src="{{ a.img_post.url }}">
```

Для вывода связанной модели с изображениями:

```
def detail(request, home_id):
    a = Article.objects.get(id=home_id)
    images = Image.objects.filter(Article=a)
    return render(request, 'home/detail.html',  {'a': a, 'images': images})
```

html:

```
{% for image in images %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

И переименуйте вашу переменную `Article` на `article` т.к. У вас переменная может конфликтовать с классом.

Так же, прочтите [PEP8](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html)

Comment: MEDIA_URL и MEDIA_ROOT настроены так `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

Comment: @Марк А ответ помог?

Comment: да, но не без костылей